# Elixir regex matching literal backslash

Tags: regex, erlang, elixir, elixir-iex

Surprisingly the regex matcher does not match backslash correcly. For example

```
Regex.split(~r{\\}, "C:\foo\bar")
["C:\foo\bar"]
Regex.match?(~r/\\/, "C:\foo\bar")
false
```

I would expect a positive match, but maybe I'm escaping `\` wrong. Let's test that out:

```
Regex.escape("\\")
"\\\\"
Regex.split(~r{\\\\}, "C:\foo\bar")
["C:\foo\bar"]
Regex.match?(~r/\\\\/, "C:\foo\bar")
false
```

Still no match. Fairly confused at this point. How do you escape `\` in a regex to match a literal `\` as you can see in my usecase I would like to split a windows path.

Comment: What does `Regex.split(~r{\}, "C:\foo\bar")` produce?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus obviously it does not produce anything, it cannot be parsed because the closing parenthesis is still inside a regular expression, opened with `~r{` and never closed (closing curly is escaped with a backslash.)

Comment: Another option (since I'm guessing you're using Windows) is "C:/foo/bar"  Forward slashes do work on Windows but there are odd little gotcha's to be aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is fine; your input is not what you think it is. Backslash inside strings *escapes*.

```rb
String.split("C:\foo\bar", "")
#⇒ ["", "C", ":", "\f", "o", "o", "\b", "a", "r", ""]

String.length("C:\foo\bar")
#⇒ 8
```

Note `"\f"` and `"\b"` there. The string contains no backslash, but it contains `"\f"` and `"\b"` codepoints.

That said, you need to pass *a proper* string to `Regex.split/3` to yield the expected result.

```rb
Regex.split(~r|\\|, "C:\\foo\\bar")
#⇒ ["C:", "foo", "bar"]
```